# Does my function enter the positive region?

Tags: equation-solving

The following Plot shows erratic behavior unless working precision is set appropriately:

```
With[{w = 1/2, f = 1/2}, Plot[1 + 1/(2 (f - f P)^2) P (1/(-1 + w) (Log[-f + (1 + f) P] - Log[P + f (-1 + P) (-1 + 2 w)]) (-f + (1 + f) P) + 1/w (Log[f - (-1 + f) P] - Log[P + f (-1 + P) (-1 + 2 w)]) (-f + (-1 + f) P)), {P, 999/1000, 1}]]
```

[image]

But how can I be sure (can I be sure, even using Mathematica?) the function never enters the positive region?

Comment: I'd say the earlier question is effectively a duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/180355/12 (or they should me merged in some way instead of having two posts)

Answer (score 1):

```
With[{w = 1/2, f = 1/2}, 
 Reduce[{1 + 
     1/(2 (f - f P)^2) P (1/(-1 + w) (Log[-f + (1 + f) P] - 
           Log[P + f (-1 + P) (-1 + 2 w)]) (-f + (1 + f) P) + 
        1/w (Log[f - (-1 + f) P] - 
           Log[P + f (-1 + P) (-1 + 2 w)]) (-f + (-1 + f) P)) > 0,
   999/1000 <= P <= 1
   }, P]]
```

> False

`False` means that this can never happen.